# PHP XSLT transforming BR tag into <br></br>

Tags: php, xslt, google-chrome

I am facing strange issue while using XSLT in PHP. All the br tags in XSL files are getting converting into <br></br> i.e. opening and closing of br tag.

This conversion is creating UI issues in Google Chrome browser. Chrome is converting </br> into another <br> tag hence UI is getting gabbled.

Please help me ASAP.....

Comment: Besides the serialization method point out by @Matthew Wilson, I don't think that a literal self closed empty `br` would be output as an empty element with opening and closing tags. If you are copying it from input source, the there are methods to preserve self closed empty elements even with XML serialization.

Comment: I have simple XSL file which contains <br/> after transformation the HTML contains <br></br> at the place of <br/> which is very strange for me.

When page is viewed in FF it is displayed properly but in Chrome I see two line breaks instead of one because Chrome is converting closing tat </br> into another BR tag.

It is a strange behavior I have never seen before :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question on **PHP manual site**. URL: http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.transformtoxml.php

**It was in a user comment, following is the same comment:**

$domTranObj = $xslProcessor->transformToDoc($domXmlObj);

$domHtmlText = $domTranObj->saveHTML();

Do fix the <meta> for valid XHTML but do not correctly end empty node like <br /> which ouput like this : <br></br>

Some browser note this as 2 different <br /> ...

To fix this use

$domTranObj = $xslProcessor->transformToDoc($domXmlObj);

$domHtmlText = $domTranObj->saveXML();

Answer (score 2):

Have you specified

```
<xsl:output method="html"/>
```

?